# Java API for loading TensorFlow models created in python

Tags: java, python, tensorflow, installation, java-13

I am using Java 13 (I'm not sure if that is relevant) and I'm making a blackjack game. I want to add a neural network model after training it in python to my Java application. However, on [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_java) it says

> "Note: There is no libtensorflow support for TensorFlow 2 yet."

I haven't even started making my model so I have not tried to load a model into Java. Is this going to be a problem? Do I need to use an older version of TensorFlow?

Comment: To run TF 2.0 models in Java, you can instead use TensorFlow Lite. You can build it with Gradle. See [here](https://bintray.com/google/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite).

Comment: Wow thanks! It looks like it will have decent performance as well after a short read [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference) @ShubhamPanchal

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to convert your model to TF Lite, you can also use the snapshots available for TensorFlow Java with 2.x support enabled, check this [repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/java).